# Count how many records does each user have in the second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 Tables (The relevant ones for this question). One for Customers, second for loans. 
What I am trying to accomplish is to get each customer's information, and in addition to that how many loans he toked.

#### My User Table

```
+--------+-------+-------+-----+
| cst_id | fname | lname | age |
+--------+-------+-------+-----+
|      1 | xx    | yy    |  11 |
|      2 | xx    | yy    |  22 |
|      3 | xx    | yy    |  33 |
|      4 | xx    | yy    |  44 |
|      5 | xx    | yy    |  55 |
+--------+-------+-------+-----+
```

#### Loan Table

```
+---------+-----------------+
| cust_id | loan_variant_id |
+---------+-----------------+
|       1 |               1 |
|       1 |               2 |
|       2 |               3 |
|       2 |               1 |
|       3 |               1 |
+---------+-----------------+
```

We see that customers with ID 1 have 2 registered loans.

#### How the final table should  look like

you can ignore the new column "name" because it is irrelevant to the question.

```
+--------+-------+-------+-----+-------+------------+
| cst_id | fname | lname | age | name  | loan_count |
+--------+-------+-------+-----+-------+------------+
|      1 | xx    | yy    |  11 | xx yy |          2 |
|      2 | xx    | yy    |  22 | xx yy |          2 |
|      3 | xx    | yy    |  33 | xx yy |          1 |
|      4 | xx    | yy    |  44 | xx yy |          0 |
|      5 | xx    | yy    |  55 | xx yy |          0 |
+--------+-------+-------+-----+-------+------------+
```

#### My SQL code

```
SELECT
    *,
    CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) AS name,
    COUNT(##some magic code please, at least what i think##) AS loan_count
FROM
    t_cst
```

Now I know that via this query I can accomplish what I want (counting How many loans are token by each user) in the t_loans table. However, I am kind of stuck on how to use both queries together.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(cust_id) AS loansCountForEachCst
FROM
    t_loans
GROUP BY
    (cust_id)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Side observation, try and be consistent with naming conventions. i.e. Either use "cust" or "cst" but not both.  Better yet, spell out the word "Customer" so others reviewing the schema don't have to guess what it means :-)

Comment: @SOS oh yeah, forgive me man. it was like mid of the night XD. i will correct it now. thank you

Comment: Heh, some of my best typos were made in the wee hours of the night ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a simple `GROUP BY` and an `OUTER JOIN` to include all the customers even if they have no loans:

```
SELECT
    c.cst_id,
    c.fname,
    c.lname,
    c.age,
    CONCAT(c.fname, ' ', c.lname) AS name,
    COUNT(l.loan_variant_id) AS loan_count
FROM
    t_cst c
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    t_loans l ON c.cst_id = l.cust_id
GROUP BY
    c.cst_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.age
```

The catch is that we have to capture all the common outputs in the `GROUP BY` clause.

See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd7ee73/2

Comment: Oops, Updated to use outer join!

Comment: Yeah, that solved the problem, Thank you for the clean code.